# What would happen if everything in a radius stopped exhibiting quantum properties and acted like if it was constantly being observed?

Tags: science-based, physics, quantum

Okay here's the lore. In my universe Dark matter is in reality an entity that exists in a higher dimension constantly observing everything that passes through itself. This means that whatever object that is in the dark matter will stop exhibiting quantum properties due to the fact that the waveform has been collapsed.

So my question is: Would objects have different properties in this case? What might happen if an organism or computer passes through my dark matter? Would anything at all change?

Comment: @storymode Sounds like a proper answer to me.

Comment: You misunderstand "waveform collapse." It doesn't actually collapse, it resolves to a single value instead of a cloud of probabilities. It doesn't actually stop being the cloud of probabilities, any more than a bullet stops moving when it passes through a piece of paper.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are misunderstanding the popularized concepts of quantum physics when they talk about an observer causing the collapse of the wave functions and all the connected shebang.

As stated in the answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/343602):

> Do quantum events depend on the presence of observer?
>
> The answer is ultimately yes, but the definition of observer in quantum mechanics is counterintuitively far from its colloquial definition, which is typically taken as "some conscious entity that does not interfere with a process." Instead, a quantum-mechanical observer is anything that interacts with a quantum system in such a way as to extract information from that system.
>
> When you substitute the quantum-mechanical definition of observer in your statement, it reads: "Quantum systems are influenced by things that interact with them," which is now obviously true.

Based on the above, your Dark Matter is doing nothing more than whatever other matter is doing, by "observing" whatever is around. No changes at all.

Answer (score 4):

**Complex Matter Cannot Exist**

Atoms require quantum phenomena to exist. Perhaps you are familiar with the Bohr model of the atom as a bunch of playpit balls in the middle with electrons whizzing around in circles.

[image]

Some of the circles are bigger than others. These are called electron shells.

In fact the Bohr model is inaccurate. If you try to describe it classically, the electrons get sucked into the core and the atom is no more.

The real setup requires quantum stuff to explain. Oh and the orbits are not orbits in the classical sense. They are differently-shaped probability clouds.

[image]

The upshot is that if you remove quantum from the equation, you either (a) get an existence failure for all nearby quantum matter (at the very least) or (b) must replace the quantum with some other sort of fictional physics. In that case anything can happen. But coming up with an alternate set of physics sounds like a tall order.

Comment: "The Bohr model is inaccurate." This is true and nothing anyone should be surprised about. After all, Newton's laws of gravity are inaccurate for the same reason. *We've learned more about our universe, and in doing so, demonstrated that previous models are too simple.* The problem is that haven't-yet-taken-college-classes worldbuilders don't get that the assertion is just as true for what we know today. *What we know today is inaccurate.* We just haven't learned enough about our universe yet to prove that to be true. Personally, I'm a fan of (4,3,0). It looks sassy to me. Sassy is good.

Comment: @JBH There is no deeper point here about the limits of current knowledge. I simply mean that the most common conception of the atom as a tiny little planet is known to be incorrect.

Comment: :-) Keep in mind I was agreeing with you.

Answer (score 1):

Straight answer: makes no difference.

The 'observation' is the [Copenhagen Interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_interpretation) - something that was patched together in the very early days of quantum physics, when people were still getting to grips with the 'particle or wave' idea. There was nothing sentient 'observing', and I wish the descriptions could let it go and move on.

Consider a photon coming from the Andromeda galaxy. It has travelled for over two million years. If it was a pure wave, it would have spread out so it had no energy. The whole electron-volt or so of energy may arrive at a single cell in your eye. And yet you can put the light through a spectrometer, and get its spectrum. What's going on here? We have a particle (the photon) and the probability that it can be found in any position spreads out as a wave with the same properties as electrodynamic waves. We cannot see or measure this wave directly without interacting with it (or 'observing' it if you like), so we cannot say 'oh, it's being a wave *here* and it's a particle *over here*. Quantum physics is wonderfully precise and it never contradicts itself, but we always stop a bit short of seeing anything like the *truth* of classical physics (which wasn't true).